# Weird typing box in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pixel

Fiddling around today I discovered if you type on the desktop version of raspbian without selecting a window it shows up in a window in the upper right. It doesn't seem to do anything other than sit there, is this a bug or just not fully implemented?

[image: screenshot of it]

Comment: I added the "pixel" tag on the presumption that this is WRT the newly forked DE: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/  Although there's no mention of it there, so maybe it is actually a mysterious feature from LXDE.

Comment: Good question, it doesn't do anything here too... just to confirm that it is not you being crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LXDE, your desktop is managed by PCManFM, which is also LXDE's file manager. PCManFM has a function to find items in a folder by typing the first letters of it. For example if you type `apple`, it'll spring to the first item that start with `apple`. Since PIXEL is just a fork of LXDE, it has that feature too.

Comment: Does it work when looking at other folders?

Comment: @sir_ian: What do you mean?

Comment: I have a folder called `story` on my desktop, if I type in story and hit enter it shows me it. But it doesn't look like I can look at anything other than what is on my desktop. True?

Comment: @sir_ian: That's true, it's just for jumping to an item in the current folder…